How to force renovate to set azure pipeline task from "x@1" to "x@2" instead of "x@2.0.5"
[CONTEXT]
I use renovate (azure-pipeline manager) to update my YML azure pipelines tasks.
[NEED]
If my pipeline calls my-task@1, I don't want a PR that sets my-task@2.0.5, I want to keep this notation my-task@2.
Hence, I keep using the latest minor/patch at each execution.
[RESEARCHES]
LLMs keep saying wrong suggestions using any config tag containing "version" or whatever, even with fine tuned and detailed prompts.
I have read the whole Renovate config page without finding my answer... Maybe I missed something. Thanks in advance.


If my pipeline calls my-task@1, I don't want a PR that sets my-task@2.0.5, I want to keep this notation my-task@2.

As per your requirement, you want only major version to update.
You can try to use matchUpdateTypes to match only major version, and add "extractVersion": "^(?<version>\\d+)" in renovate.json for the trick.
{
  "azure-pipelines": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["azure-pipelines-tasks"],
      "extractVersion": "^(?<version>\\d+)"
    },
    {
      "packageNames": ["DownloadBuildArtifacts"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["major"],
      "labels": ["UPDATE-MAJOR"]
    }
  ]
}

The PR created:


I am already using "matchUpdateTypes": ["major"] to create PRs only for major update.
I tried the "rangeStrategy": "pin" but it skips all pipeline tasks with the following reason: "skipReason": "invalid-value". Hence, no PR is created at all.
However, "extractVersion": "^(?<version>\\d+)" did the trick. Could you please  Update you response to highlight that THIS is the proper tag to add ? Else I can write another answer precising that. Thank you very much.

Thanks @Mario for the info, i have updated the answer. Happy coding! :)
